# Are electron dipolar spin-spin interactions included in DFT calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory

I am studying point defects in hBN using Quantum Espresso. It is not clear if electron spin-spin interactions are typically/can be included in DFT calculations. I understand that spin-orbit interactions can be included in the calculation by performing a noncollinear calculation with lspinorb = .true.. I have also found some papers which discuss zero-field-splitting, but cannot find much information about magnetic dipole-dipole interactions. It would make sense to me if the interaction was included in the functional, but it appears that only the Coulomb interaction is considered (I am using the HSE functional). Perhaps spin-polarized calculations somehow include the spin-spin interaction?

Comment: Also note that there is the [Matter Modelling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks Nihar! I wasn't aware of this.